# EXPLAIN ANALYZE Not Running on Query

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan, explain

I have a large query I am trying to analyze to improve the efficiency. I first ran just `EXPLAIN`:

```
 EXPLAIN 
    SELECT * FROM pop_allocation_sql.main_parcels_cb_intersects
    WHERE parcel_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT parcel_id::int 
    FROM pop_allocation_sql.main_bldgs_cb_intersects)
```

And it returned the following within seconds:

```
Gather  (cost=20506897.97..3330358572517.40 rows=40283932 width=89)
Workers Planned: 7
->  Parallel Seq Scan on main_parcels_cb_intersects  (cost=20505897.97..3330354543124.20 rows=5754847 width=89)
    Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
    SubPlan 1
      ->  Materialize  (cost=20505897.97..21069329.24 rows=6107669 width=4)
            ->  Unique  (cost=20505897.97..21014931.89 rows=6107669 width=4)
                  ->  Sort  (cost=20505897.97..20760414.93 rows=101806784 width=4)
                        Sort Key: ((main_bldgs_cb_intersects.parcel_id)::integer)
                        ->  Seq Scan on main_bldgs_cb_intersects  (cost=0.00..5334454.80 rows=101806784 width=4)
```

But this would not show me where the exact bottlenecks are occurring so I tried to run just:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
  SELECT * FROM pop_allocation_sql.main_parcels_cb_intersects
  WHERE parcel_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT parcel_id::int 
  FROM pop_allocation_sql.main_bldgs_cb_intersects)
```

I let this run for over an hour and nothing returned. I checked PG ADMIN and notcied the wait event said Lock: transactionid and gave a blocking PID of 119698 (I am not exactly sure what this means). Why won't my query complete?

Comment: Explain only gives a plan estimate, analyze will actually run it. That query is a poor performer , but pgadmin is saying there is another transaction modifying rows this query is attempting to read. That query is yet to commit so this is hanging.

Comment: The `distinct` in the sub-select is unnecessary. Typically an equivalent NOT EXISTS condition  is faster than a NOT IN, so try to re-write the query.

Comment: @VynlJunkie: there must be more going on here. SELECT queries aren't blocked by other queries, unless e.g. a TRUNCATE was run on that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session with process ID 119698 has a transaction open that holds an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on one of the tables in your query. End that transaction, if necessary with

```
SELECT pg_cancel_backend(119698);
```

If you want your query to perform better, rewrite it to

```
SELECT *
FROM pop_allocation_sql.main_parcels_cb_intersects AS p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT FROM  pop_allocation_sql.main_bldgs_cb_intersects AS pb
    WHERE p.parcel_id = pb.parcel_id::integer
);
```

The `DISTINCT` is quite unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, it was the lok that did it.